# Can I combine step-up and step-down designs for switched DC-DC convertor?

Tags: integrated-circuit, dc-dc-converter, circuit-design

I need to generate 5 volts from unstable source. The voltage on input will be between 2 to 7 volts. The source is hand-crafted dynamo, which I'm doing as an experiment.

I found LT1173CN8-5 DIP8 integrated circuit. [In the datasheet](https://www.gme.cz/data/attachments/dsh.332-058.1.pdf) (written for all LT1173 series circuits) they show these two examples on page 13:

[image: image description]

I'll be going with the left design, since my input voltage is most likely to be less than 5V - random peaks above can be handled by capacitors.

But is it possible to combine designs? Would that cost me efficiency?

Why is the diode on the images above actually placed completely differently?

Comment: Sounds like you need a buck-boost converter.

Comment: Linear (who make those ICs from your schematic) make many buck-boost IC's to suit your purpose. Also small power low voltage buck-boost complete modules are readily available and cheap!

Comment: I'd agree linear tech make some excellent ICs for this [see here](http://www.linear.com/products/buck-boost_regulators)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your application exists a different category of DC/DC converters called buck-boost converter which handles exactly what you are describing.

They reach efficiency levels of both designs, mostly dipping if the input is close to the output voltage.

They are available from different manufacturers, just like you'd expect.

A word of warning for your special application (I tried something similar and killed my MP3 player with it): in case of no load the voltage of your dynamo will get very high, use some sort of voltage limiting at the input of your buck-boost converter.

Comment: I have problem finding these things because I browse online stores which are in my country and partly feature translated entries, partly in english. Are there any particular ICs you would recommend?

Comment: @TomášZato depends on the output current you are looking at. The LT3129 looks nice for lower currents - you could try something fancy with the MPPT of it as well. LTC3118 for higher currents.

Comment: @TomášZato as a part of a different manufacturer the TPS63070 from TI is also a good looking part. Can't comment on how good any of these are, I actually never used a buck-boost converter so far. Linear Technology ICs often just work even with bad layouts (on breadboards), which is why I really like them.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I really appreciate it. I will try to find any buck-boost regulator, but hopefully with my current physical design, step-up will work well because I did not manage to generate higher voltages yet. Also thanks for mentioning the danger of high voltage peaks, I will think about it.